# How can the following Initial-boundary value problem be solved?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have used Laplace Transformation and got the solution in Laplace domain, but it seems very complicated to be transformed back to the real-time domain. Is it possible to solve the problem with another technique?

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t }=a^2 \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$$

The initial condition is:

$$T(x,0) = 0.5 \left(\mbox{Erfc}\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)+ e^{x} * \mbox{Erfc}\left(\frac{x + a}{b}\right)\right)$$

The boundary conditions:

$$T(\infty,t)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial T(0,t)}{\partial x }=0$$

Comment: Have you tried separation of variables?

Comment: Not yet. I will try with this technique. But how to get the arbitrary constants when x approaches infinity by this technique?

Comment: Great, I guess it should work